# My API Call is not displaying the data I am calling

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get my weather forecast website to show weather. Here is my code. I feel like I have written this correctly, but the output it stating otherwise. I have written this is Jquery.

I have a feeling there is something wrong with either the IF statement of AJAX call.

Thanks so much

PS. I intentionally took out the key for the weather app.

Thanks.

```js
// Wait until Dom has completed loading
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Testing that logic.js has been successfully linked to index.html.
  console.log("logic.js is linked successfully");

  // GLOBAL VARIABLES

  // SELECTORS
  // selectors for left side column
  let searchCity = $(".searchCity");
  let cityList = $(".cityList");

  let searchButton = $(".searchButton");
  let searchHistory = [];

  // selectors for right side column
  let weatherArea = $(".weatherArea");

  let forecastArea = $(".cardArea");

  // VARIABLES for AJAX
  let searchedCity = $(searchCity).val();
  let queryURL = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + searchedCity + "&appid=APIKEYGOESHERE"
// I took out my key for this question

  // BUILDING FUNCTIONS

  // When user clicks search button...
  $(searchButton).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("requesting weather data...");
    // Push user's search into variable array
    searchHistory.push(searchedCity);

    // If the search field is not blank...  -- This if statement may be breaking my code, still testing
    if (searchedCity != "") {
      // Locally store searchHistory -- having issues getting this to work
      localStorage.setItem("searchHistory", searchHistory);

      // Request weather data from OpenWeatherMap API
      $.ajax({
          url: queryURL,
          method: "GET",
          dataType: "jsonp",
        })
        // When weather data response is returned...
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          // Display weather data in weatherArea 
          let weatherData = show(response);
          $(weatherArea).html(weatherData);

          // Display forecast data in forecastArea

          let forecastData = "";


          // For each item in response...
          for (var i in response.list) {
            if (i > 0 && response.list[i].dt_txt.indexof("12:00") > -1) {
              // Create variable to contain forecast data
              let forecastArray = [
                "<div class = 'col-sm-2 day'>",
                "<p>",

                response.list[i].dt_txt.split(" ")[0],
                "</p>",
                "<img src = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/' + response.list[i].weather[0].icon + '@2x.png'>",
                "<p> Temp: ",

                response.list[i].main.temp,
                " degrees</p>",
                "<p> Humidity: ",

                response.list[i].main.humidity,
                "%</p>",
                "<p> Wind Speed: ",

                response.list[i].main.wind.speed,
                " mph</p>",
                "</div>"
              ];
              // Add forecast Data to forecastArray
              forecastData += forecastArray.join("");
            }
          }
          // Display forecast data in forecastArea
          $(forecastArea).html(forecastData);
          $(searchCity).val("");
        });
    }
    // If the search field is empty...
    else {
      $(weatherArea).text("Search field can't be empty");
      $(forecastArea).text("Search field can't be empty");
    }
  });
  // function for showing the response data for the weather
  function show(response) {
    console.log("Showing Response: ", response);

    return response.city.name + "<h3> (" + response.list[0].dt_txt.split(' ')[0] + ") </h3>" +
      "<p class = 'lead'>Temp: " + response.list[0].main.temp + " degrees</p>" +
      "<p class = 'lead'>Humidity: " + response.list[0].main.humidity + " %</p>" +
      "<p class = 'lead'>Wind Speed: " + response.list[0].wind.speed + " mph</p>";
  };
  // Get searh history from local storage and display in cityList
  function showHistory() {
    let searchStorage = localStorage.getItem("searchHistory")
    $(cityList).append("<tr>").append("<td>" + searchStorage + "</td>")
  };

  showHistory();

  // Close of 'document.ready' function
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">
  <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Row 1 - Header -->
  <header class="topBar">
    <row>
      <h1 class="pageTitle">Weather Dashboard</h1>
    </row>
  </header>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Row 2 - Body -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Row 2, Column 1 - left side -->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <!-- Row 2, Column 1, Row a - City Search -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row searchTitle">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2 class="lead">Search for a City:</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row searchArea">
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="searchCity" placeholder="Choose a city...">
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                                        <i class = "fa fa-search"></i>
                                    </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row 2, Column 1, Row b - City List -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-11 listArea">
            <table class="cityList">
              <tr>
                <th>Recent Searches</th>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-1">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Row 2, Column 2 - right side -->
      <div class="col-sm-9 rightSide">
        <!-- Row 2, Column 2, Row a - Current Weather -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="weatherArea">
              <p>weather area</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row 2, Column 2, Row b - 5-day Forecast Title -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="forecastTitle">
              <h2 class="lead">5-Day Forecast:</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row 2, Column 2, Row c - 5-day Forecast Cards -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row cardArea">
              <div class="col-sm-2.2">
                <div class="card forecast-01">
                  <div class="card-body bg-info">forecast</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-0.25"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2.2">
                <div class="card forecast-02">
                  <div class="card-body bg-info">forecast</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-0.25"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2.2">
                <div class="card forecast-03">
                  <div class="card-body bg-info" id="cardBody">forecast</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-0.25"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2.2">
                <div class="card forecast-04">
                  <div class="card-body bg-info">forecast</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-0.25"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-2.2">
                <div class="card forecast-05">
                  <div class="card-body bg-info">forecast</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Links to js libraries and external logic sheet -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./assets/logic.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem. "I feel like I have written this correctly, but the output it stating otherwise" is very vague. What is the difference between what your are expecting and what you are receiving? Is the problem with the data received or how you are displaying it?

Answer (score 0):

Just some small changes to your code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qdv49.png

```
// Wait until Dom has completed loading
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Testing that logic.js has been successfully linked to index.html.
  console.log("logic.js is linked successfully");

  // GLOBAL VARIABLES

  // SELECTORS
  // selectors for left side column
  let searchCity = $(".searchCity");
  let cityList = $(".cityList");

  let searchButton = $(".searchButton");
  let searchHistory = [];

  // selectors for right side column
  let weatherArea = $(".weatherArea");

  let forecastArea = $(".cardArea");

  // BUILDING FUNCTIONS

  // When user clicks search button...
  $(searchButton).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("requesting weather data...");

    //GET VALUE WHEN CLICKED
    // VARIABLES for AJAX
    let searchedCity = $(searchCity).val();
    let queryURL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + searchedCity + "&appid=YOUR_KEY"
    // I took out my key for this question

    // Push user's search into variable array
    searchHistory.push(searchedCity);

    // If the search field is not blank...  -- This if statement may be breaking my code, still testing
    if (searchedCity != "") {
      // Locally store searchHistory -- having issues getting this to work
      localStorage.setItem("searchHistory", searchHistory);

      // Request weather data from OpenWeatherMap API
      $.ajax({
          url: queryURL,
          method: "GET",
          dataType: "jsonp",
        })
        // When weather data response is returned...
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          // Display weather data in weatherArea 
          let weatherData = show(response);
          $(weatherArea).html(weatherData);

          // Display forecast data in forecastArea

          let forecastData = "";


          // For each item in response...
          for (var i in response.list) {
            if (i > 0 && response.list[i].dt_txt.indexOf("12:00") > -1) { //NOT indexof
              // Create variable to contain forecast data
              let forecastArray = [
                "<div class = 'col-sm-2 day'>",
                "<p>",

                response.list[i].dt_txt.split(" ")[0],
                "</p>",
                "<img src = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + response.list[i].weather[0].icon + "@2x.png'>", //CORRECTED THIS
                "<p> Temp: ",

                response.list[i].main.temp,
                " degrees</p>",
                "<p> Humidity: ",

                response.list[i].main.humidity,
                "%</p>",
                "<p> Wind Speed: ",

                response.list[i].wind.speed,//NOT response.list[i].main.wind.speed,
                " mph</p>",
                "</div>"
              ];
              // Add forecast Data to forecastArray
              forecastData += forecastArray.join("");
            }
          }
          // Display forecast data in forecastArea
          $(forecastArea).html(forecastData);
          $(searchCity).val("");
        });
    }
    // If the search field is empty...
    else {
      $(weatherArea).text("Search field can't be empty");
      $(forecastArea).text("Search field can't be empty");
    }
  });
  // function for showing the response data for the weather
  function show(response) {
    console.log("Showing Response: ", response);

    return response.city.name + "<h3> (" + response.list[0].dt_txt.split(' ')[0] + ") </h3>" +
      "<p class = 'lead'>Temp: " + response.list[0].main.temp + " degrees</p>" +
      "<p class = 'lead'>Humidity: " + response.list[0].main.humidity + " %</p>" +
      "<p class = 'lead'>Wind Speed: " + response.list[0].wind.speed + " mph</p>";
  };
  // Get searh history from local storage and display in cityList
  function showHistory() {
    let searchStorage = localStorage.getItem("searchHistory")
    $(cityList).append("<tr>").append("<td>" + searchStorage + "</td>")
  };

  showHistory();

  // Close of 'document.ready' function
});
```